# Setting text below the icon rather than on right in QTableView?

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

I'm adding images as items to a QTableView, I'm also adding a specific text to each images, problem is the text is shown beside the image or the icon, but I want QTableView to show it below the image or the icon. My code snippet is as below:

```
QStandardItemModel * model = new QStandardItemModel(NumOfRow, 3, this);
```

Then comes this part which is in the loop

```
//

    QStandardItem * itm = new QStandardItem;
    itm->setIcon(image);
    itm->setText(text);
    model->setItem(row, column, itm);
//
```

Then this part outside the loop

```
ui->listOfImages->setModel(model);
ui->listOfImages->setStyleSheet(QString("icon-size: 150px 150px"));
ui->listOfImages->verticalHeader()->setVisible(false);
ui->listOfImages->horizontalHeader()->setVisible(false);
for(int i=0; i<=rowPointer; i++)
{
    ui->listOfImages->setRowHeight(i,150);
}
for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
{
    ui->listOfImages->setColumnWidth(j,150);
}
```

Could you say me if there is any way to put the name below the icon rather than in the right side of the icon?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would try to handle the text alignment with the custom `QStandardItemModel` sub class. Here is the sample model, that implements it:

```
class ItemModel : public QStandardItemModel
{
public:
    ItemModel(int rows, int columns, QObject *parent = 0)
        :
            QStandardItemModel(rows, columns, parent)
    {}

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
    {
        if (role == Qt::TextAlignmentRole) {
            return Qt::AlignBottom; // <- Make alignment look different, i.e.
                                    // <- text at the bottom.
        } else {
            return QStandardItemModel::data(index, role);
        }
    }
};
```

So, instead of using the Qt class, you will need to create an instance of this custom class:

```
QStandardItemModel * model = new ItemModel(NumOfRow, 3, this);
```

The rest will remain the same.

Comment: Unfortunately all it changed is now showing the text in the corner, I think we actually need to change the item with custom class for the Item. When I see the icon, it's clear that icon's image is in a separate box from the its text, some how I need to bring the text box down under the icon itself.

Comment: What if you try to do the same with QListWidget?